# Unable to find "my survey" in content in marketing cloud. can we create polls or surveys in our SFMC account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I am trying to create a Survey in Marketing Cloud but I am not able to find the "my survey" option in the content of the Marketing cloud. How to create a poll or survey in the Marketing cloud

Comment: Hi Neha. Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

[Surveys](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_survey.htm&type=5) were part of Classic Content, and are [not available anymore](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_january_2019_update_to_classic_content_end_of_support_plan.htm&type=5). You can create a Cloud Page with a [Smart Form](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_cp_create_a_smart_capture_form_in_cloudpages.htm&type=5) instead, if you want to collect information in a form, and pass it on to a data extension.